# Create a c/c++ application (with Xlib) to render SWF files

Tags: c++, c, browser, flash, xlib

Constraint : AS to be in C/C++

SO basically, the idea is to create my own window application (on a Linux environment) and load up (play) my swf file. Pretty "simple" question.

I was thinking to go with Xlib without widgets (so no Qt, GITK, etc.) and I'm kind of wondering if any libraries exist to open swf... I have stubbled upon SWFDEC, but not too sure about it.

I'm looking for insight. How would you guys do it?

Thank you. I'll keep you updated on the workflow I'm taking ;)

EDIT (1): Any C Library for playing with SWF?

**EDIT (2): How about using a Plugin API ([NNP](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2002/plugin/1.0/intro.html))**

Comment: ...and why are you creating your own browser?

Comment: Sorry. I should have said window application on a Linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way with NPAPI. Working my way there, but this will do the job.
I have read tremendous amount of documentation over the past days (very hard, since it's a little bit old), but finally found a great example/sample to achieve what I want.

http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/trunk/samples/unix-basic/BasicPlugin.c
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins

So, my whole thing is in C and using Xlib (not GTK) and I have the libflashplayer.so .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538218/xml-config-file-wont-load-on-swf-display-npapi-gtk2

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at GameSWF

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameSWF

Comment: Any tutorial or documentation on this?

Comment: All I know is that Scaleform GFX is derived from this originally.  http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform/features/overview

Comment: Looks like it hasn't been updated for 5 or so years. Just saying.

Comment: Sure, the project like this must either be commercial from the beginning or at least transform into the commercial one later. The ScaleformGFX is what this has become.

Comment: If it is a serious project, why not use the http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html   ?